# API-ключи для авторизации в личном кабинете интернет-магазина

Tags: авторизация

Чтобы настроить авторизацию в личном кабинете интернет-магазина мне нужны:
ID-приложения и API-токен приложения. Для этого в настройках учетной записи нужно ввести URL-адрес для перенаправления, но я не нахожу необходимого поля для ввода адреса. Создается один ключ,а нужен еще ID-приложения. Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: вероятно я задам глупый вопрос, какой магазин?

Comment: Интернет-магазин на InSales

Comment: https://www.insales.ru/support